# Process.start not opening pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, process, exe

I am stuck with a problem and need urgent help in it.

I have a .Net application where, in one of the functions, I need to open Adobe Reader (AcroRd32.exe). I do it using Process.Start method. It worked in my system perfectly but not on the server.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe");
```

Also I tried creating a test application which just has the `Process.Start` statement. That works! it opens AcroRd32.exe! But the same statement doesn't work inside a function of my application.
The function never experiences any error or exception and I can see AcroRd32.exe running in the task manager. I tried putting notifications before and after the `Process.Start` statement and both are getting executed.

What might be the problem? is it because am using it inside a function?

Comment: Why don't you do a Process.Start on the pdf file itself?

Comment: Why do you expect AcroRd32.exe to work "server side"?

Comment: i cant.. my application uses pdf according to the selection of user.. so no particular pdf..

Comment: @Ian.. i did it using a test application... it just doesnt work in my application.. i want the pdf to be opened and then sent for printing... i can handle the printing if only the pdf would open ..

Comment: By "server", are you referring a "web server"? Is this a web application? If it is, then the acrobat will be opened only in the server, not in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your application is running under a different user account in the server than the one logged in.

Comment: oh.. can you please explain? and is there a way to rectify that?

Comment: No, I can't, because I know nothing about your application.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a security issue as Daniel Pointed out. Check out these websites and see how the issue was resolved: http://forums.asp.net/t/1159342.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134